# Teradata Fast Load (Third-party databases)

Tags: oracle, teradata

Is it possible to load data (from text file) into Oracle using Teradata FastLoad? If so what is a generic statement to do so.

I looked at TeradataFast load documentation but I do not see any demonstration on how it is done.

Comment: SQL Assistant doesn't use FastLoad, as far as I know. If you want to use Oracle, use Oracle tools, like `SQL*Loader`.

Comment: @Andrew , sorry I have updated question. You are correct, FastLoad is a different utility and separate from Teradata SQL Assistant (they are both included as option to be downloaded in TeradataToolsAndUtilitiesBase). My question still remains the same, is it possible to use Teradata Fast Load to load a flat file into oracle database? I would use SQL*Loader but I am on the client-side and our oracle database is 11.2. Unfortunately I would not be able to use the oracle tool.

Comment: Fastload loads to Teradata and that's it. You'll need an Oracle ETL tool to load Oracle.

Comment: SQL*Loader is designed to load files from the client file system, and it's distributed with Oracle Instant Client now. You can use the 12c client with an 11g database.

Comment: you can use any Oraclle client version against 11g, as long as the server settings allow it. Use sql*loader with direct writes and parallel loads and you will see the speed is compatible to fastload. Underneath it all, they do the same thing.